# Files - I am getting error instead of giving correct path

Tags: c, gcc

I want to read a .txt file. I am getting the following errors even though I have given the correct path:

> ```
> Error1: File is undeclared first time use in function 
>
> Error2: file is undeclated first time use in function
> ```

and `\U` it is taking as escape sequence.  Please guide me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   File *file = fopen("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\files.txt", "r");
   char c;
   do 
   {
      c = fgetc(file);
      printf("%c",c);
   }
   while (c != EOF)    
   fclose(file);
   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: For such few code it is little work to have it properly formatted. Properly formatted code is question of respect to the reader.

Comment: I'd be quite wary of using a compiler that produced "file is undeclated" as an error message. You _are_ using cut&paste to to show your error messages, right?

Answer (score 4):

`File *file` should be `FILE *file` .

`fopen("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\files.txt", "r");` should be `fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\files.txt", "r");`

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
File *file = fopen("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\files.txt", "r");
```

has two errors:

1. The `FILE` type is spelled like that, in all-caps. Remember that C is case-sensitive.
2. Backslashes in strings are used to escape control characters, if you want a literal backslash, it must be doubled.

So, it should be:

```
FILE *file = fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\files.txt", "r");
```

Answer (score 3):

- Change `File` to `FILE`.
- Change `while (c != EOF);` to `while(!feof(file));`
- Add semicolon `;` after `while`.
- Change single Backslash `\` to Double Backslash `\\`

You code now looks like:

```
FILE *file = fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\files.txt", "r");
 char c;
 do 
 {
      c = fgetc(file);
      printf("%c",c);
 }
while(!feof(file));  
fclose(file);

system("PAUSE");  
return 0;
```

Tested this code and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You must escape all backslashes writing `"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\files.txt"`